# Converting mathematical operator as string argument to real operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am creating a program in javascript and I don't know how I can achieve following; My program takes argument such as "+","-" and other mathematical operators as string which I want to convert to real operators. For example (Pseudo-code):

```
function calc(a,b,c, op1,op2){

  output=(a op1 b op2  c)
 }
```

calc(2,3,4,"+","-")

Output should be now = 2+3-4.

However, I don't know in advance how many operators I will have and also the numbers. In other words, my objective is to replace 1,"+",2, "-",4,"+","(",5,"+",6,")".........and so on with 1+2-4+(5+6).....

How can I implement this in a nice manner?

Comment: Do you need to support precedence and nesting, or arbitrary length expressions?

Comment: Yeah @dystroy's solution is ok for a basic solver, but you probably would want to have a proper expression tokenizer and a parser for anything more complex (or use eval if you can trust the input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could use `eval` but you can do simply this :

```
   var funcs = {
       '+': function(a,b){ return a+b },
       '-': function(a,b){ return a-b }
   };
   function calc(a,b,c, op1,op2){
      return funcs[op2](funcs[op1](a, b), c);
   }
```

You can easily extend the `funcs` map with other operators.

Comment: I think you have better solution than this one. I have not checked it but superficially looking at it, I am trying to replace the  string based mathematical form of any length to actual mathematical form. Don't you think this might be too lengthy? Just a thought from my naive mind.

Comment: Yes, it don't. That's what I also thought.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades and no, it's not too long. It's better to avoid `eval`

Comment: "However, I don't know in advance how many operators I will have and also the numbers", so a `reduce` will probably be needed here

Answer (score 1):

I really would suggest using `eval` for this particular case:

```
eval("var res = " + 1 + "+" + 2 + "-" + 4 + "+" + "(" + 5 + "+" + 6 + ")");
console.log(res); //10
```

I know, I know, everone says you should avoid `eval` where possible. And they are right. `eval` has great power and you should only use it with great responsibility, in particular when you evaluate something, that was entered by the end user. But if you are careful, you can use `eval` and be fine.

Comment: Note, however, that `eval` is _extremely_ slow

Comment: @thg435 It well take years to complete (as opposed to merely hours or days) if you do it very often.

Comment: @JanDvorak right, that also. But I'm not even sure if it would be that much slower than the alternative, parsing by hand.

Comment: @basilikum noted. I suggest a redesign of the application :-)

Answer (score 1):

This has been done very quickly, but should do the trick([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qfTS/)):

```
function executeMath() {
    if (arguments.length % 2 === 0) return null;
    var initialLength = arguments.length,
        numberIndex = (initialLength + 1)/2,
        numbers = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0, numberIndex),
        operands = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0),
        joiner = new Array(arguments.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        joiner[i*2] = numbers[i];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < operands.length; i++) {
        joiner[1+(i*2)] = operands[i];
    }
    var command = ("return (" + joiner.join('') + ");"),
        execute = new Function(command);
    console.log(command);
    return execute();
}
console.log(executeMath(2, 3, 4, 5, "/", "+", "%"));
```